# how to call the value of the primary key

Tags: php

in my system....after login i want show user profile by their passport number. i set up passport number as a primary key and the type of this passport number is varchar in my phpmyadmin database. Now i dont know what should i put in the global GET variable. i wrote varchar in the bracket but its saying undefined variable $userid and in the 2nd last line how should i write this command getUserById. Here is the screenshot of my database

[image]

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
 <?php 

if (isset($_GET['passport_IC'])) {
       $userid=()$_GET['passport_IC'];
}

$user= new User();

  ?>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2>User Profile<span class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-info" href="index.php">Back</a></h2>
      </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
               <div style="max-width: 600px; margin:0 auto">
  <?php 

        $userdata=$user->getUserById($userid);
        if ($userdata) {

   ?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you mean once user login in the system then you have to display login user profile details?

Comment: yeah. Based on the passport number.

Comment: ok. so User login fields are passport_number and password. correct?

Comment: i login to the system by email and password

Comment: This line: `$userid=()$_GET['passport_IC'];` seems incomplete. From your description I assume you are trying to get a user record from a database. To do so, you have to: 1. make a connection to your database, 2. escape the $_GET['passport_IC'] for security (e.g. using [mysql_real_escape_string](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)), 3. do a query on your database to select the user row with the given passport_IC.

Comment: if i want to follow number 2 then what should i put in the blank of the bracket.**$userid=()$_GET

Comment: You don't write varchar in there. Do you have any database / mysql functionality in php? Or how did you fill the database to begin with?

Comment: Maybe you should look into this function: `getUserById($id)` and then create something similar but `getUserByPassportIc($ic)`.

Comment: @MimHsan, I can suggest you that when user login in the system then stores the information which you want in the session. and display on your view page.

Comment: yeah  i did but when i write **$userid=(varchar)$_GET – this code its showing unexpected ....for varchar

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an admin panel your approach is ok, but if you want to show the user profile after logging the user, **do not use a GET variable**. Using a GET variable would mean that any logged in user could try changing the GET variable to try and access other user profiles. What you should do instead is save some kind of session variable after login. Ideally, this could even be the primary key for identifying the user that logged in (in your example, this would be the passport number). For example:

```
// login.php
session_start();
$_SESSION["userId"] = $passportIC;
```

That being done, in the profile page you could do:

```
// user_profile.php
$passportIC = $_SESSION["userId"]; // or $_GET["userId"] if, in fact, this is an admin panel

// Run some kind of query (assumming $db is a valid PDO connection)
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE passport_IC = :passport LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':passport', $passportIC);
$stmt->execute();

// This query should always return 1 element
if ($stmt->rowCount !== 1) {
     throw new \Exception("Logged in user not found in the database");
}

// Fetch user from the database 
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

`$user` now holds all the information of the user as an array, which you can now use in your page as you see fit.

Just as a final note, consider using a database adapter for database queries (i.e. `doctrine\dbal`), a PSR-7 library for not accessing $_GET and $_POST superglobals directly (i.e. `zend\zend-diactoros`) and a session library for not accessing the $_SESSION superglobal directly (i.e. `zendframework/zend-session`).

Comment: thanks for your answer. but just i want to know if i GET variable then whats is the problem in my above code and what should i write specially this line         <?php 

if (isset($_GET['passport_IC'])) {
       $userid=()$_GET['passport_IC'];
}

Comment: This is the function which i am calling
   public function  getUser($userid){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE passport_IC=:passport_IC Limit 1";
  $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindValue(':passport_IC',$userid);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return $result;
   }
}

Comment: If that line is the one thing that is making your script not work, it must be because of the extra parenthesis. Replace it with <?php $userid = $_GET['passport_IC'] ?? null; ?>. Also bear in mind in your getUser function that the $userid will not always be defined. That is, if there is no GET variable, you will be passing an empty variable to the function, but the prepared statement expects a string. You should write an if statement inside the function (i.e., if(is_string($userId) { }) to take that case into account.